# Node / JS create new instance right upon import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to make an instance of a class without importing the class first and making `new` afterwards.

Instead of

```
var mainClass = require('../dist/main'); // has "class Main { ... }"
var mainInstance = new mainClass();
```

I want

```
var mainInstance = new require('../dist/main').Main();
```

But something with the syntax is wrong.

```
var main = new require('../dist/main').Main();
                                       ^
TypeError: Class constructor Main cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Is this even possible? I use a combination of TypeScript and plain JS.

Comment: What's the actual syntax error you get?

Comment: @erbridge see my update

Comment: If you want there to only ever be one instance, you could just export an instance instead of the class, to prevent misuse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to achieve that:

```
var main = new (require('../dist/main').Main)();
```

And if your `module.exports` was solely exporting a class you'd do it like following:

```
var main = new (require('../dist/main'))();
```

Comment: You can also wrap the `require` call: `new (require('../dist/main')).Main()`.